# Strange jumps in val_loss for Keras mobile_net based model

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I am trying to train a model based on MobileNet to do landmark detection for Dog Faces (output is a tensor with x/y coordinates for the position of the eyes and the nose of the dog).

In my training, I am seeing the following graph for **val_loss**:

[image]

**Question**: What is going on with the random spikes in val_loss?

My model looks like this:

```py
model = applications.MobileNet(weights="imagenet",
                               include_top=False,
                               input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
for layer in model.layers:
  layer.trainable = True

x = model.output

p = 0.6

x = AveragePooling2D()(output_layer)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=1, name="net_out")(x)
x = Dropout(p/4)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(p)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(p/2)(x)

# PREDICT_SIZE is 6 - the number of landmarks I'm extracting
x = Dense(PREDICT_SIZE, activation="linear")(x)
points = Reshape((PREDICT_SIZE,), name="f")(x)

model_final = Model(input=model.input, output=points)
model_final.compile(loss="mse",
                    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(epsilon=1e-7), 
                    metrics=["accuracy"])
```

**Further questions**: Should I set epsilon to be an even bigger number in my optimizer? Will my model suffer if I make epsilon larger?

Should I try a different loss function?

Is the model itself at fault?

Should I try different top layers for my model?

---

**Update**: Removing the "relu" activation resulted both in no more funky jumps in val_loss, but also in a model with lower loss and even better precision! WOOHOO!

Here's the **val_loss** value after removing "relu" from the top layers (and no other changes).

[image]

Comment: I get such spikes when using 'relu'. At the end I simply avoid relu because it's more trouble than solution to me. (Maybe I'm not aware of how to use it properly).

Comment: Please notice that your loss is still extremely low. This spike might be caused by a case which is edgy and model for some reason got it wrong. I wouldn't care so much about it.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks so much for the recommendation! Indeed removing "relu" not only resulted in no more funky jumps, but also in a better model! Thank you so much!

Comment: @OctavianCostache Could you clarify what you meant by removing 'relu'? Is it that you're not using any activation (linear activation) now?